# Configuring bridging between a linux containers (LXC) interface and the hosts

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I want to run 2 LXC containers under a host, and I want each to have their own IP on the network, let's say the host has 10.10.1.10 and the containers have 10.10.1.11 and 10.10.1.12.

Does my setup require that I configure 2 bridged interfaces in the hosts /etc/network/interfaces file, something like this:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
   address 10.10.1.11 #ip of our host
   netmask 255.255.255.0 #subnet of our host
   network 10.10.1.0 #network of our host
   broadcast 10.10.1.255 #our broadcast address
   gateway 10.10.1.1 #default gw for our host to access the internet
   bridge_ports eth0
   bridge_fd 9
   bridge_hello 2
   bridge_maxage 12
   bridge_stp off

auto br1
iface br0 inet static
   address 10.10.1.12 #ip of our host
   netmask 255.255.255.0 #subnet of our host
   network 10.10.1.0 #network of our host
   broadcast 10.10.1.255 #our broadcast address
   gateway 10.0.1.1 #default gw for our host to access the internet
   bridge_ports eth0
   bridge_fd 9
   bridge_hello 2
   bridge_maxage 12
   bridge_stp off
```

Or is there another way to configure the host more like a switch and allow the individual containers to configure their own IPs *(that would be safer so we're not always changing the interfaces file whenever we move containers around).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use one bridge on the host.**

The LXC config file dictates what the guest/containers IP addressing will be.

```
# ifconfig 
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:C7:47:62:9C:02  
          inet addr:10.2.0.6  Bcast:10.2.127.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e611:5bff:febe:b62a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1756184372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:470262588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:112684582109 (104.9 GiB)  TX bytes:657886062154 (612.7 GiB)
```

And a sample LXC config file...

```
# cat /etc/lxc/Analytics.conf 
lxc.utsname = Analytics
lxc.tty = 4
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.mtu = 1500
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.2.0.80/17
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:30:6E:08:EC:80
lxc.rootfs = /srv/lxc/Analytics
lxc.mount = /etc/lxc/Analytics.fstab
lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = a
# /dev/null and zero
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:5 rwm
# consoles
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:1 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:0 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:0 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:1 rwm
# /dev/{,u}random
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:9 rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:8 rwm
# /dev/pts/*
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 136:* rwm
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 5:2 rwm
# rtc
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 254:0 rwm
```